# В pycharm вместо кириллицы отображаются знаки вопроса

Tags: python, парсер, pycharm

При закачке html-страницы для дальнейшей работы с ней, вместо кириллицы отображаются знаки вопроса.
Язык ОС(Windows 7) - русский. Настройки в pycharm: Global encoding - UTF-8, Project encoding - UTF-8. Вроде бы все настройки соответствуют требованиям для работы с кириллицей, но все так же отображаются знаки вопроса. Внизу предоставлен участок кода, отвечающий за скачивание, может быть, проблема в нем?

```python
headers = {
    "accept":"*/*",
    "User_Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome"
}
url = 'https://health-diet.ru/table_calorie/?utm_source=leftMenu&utm_medium=table_calorie'
src = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
with open('index.html','w') as file:
    file.write(src.text)
```

[image: Настройки кодировки в PyCharm]

[image: Настройки языка в ОС Windows]

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "закачкой" html-страницы?

Comment: Так не факт, что вы саму страницу правильным образом и в правильной кодировке скачали. Она может быть в другой кодировке, например `cp1251`.

Comment: _"Вроде бы все настройки соответствуют требованиям для работы с кириллицей"_ - на самом деле нет. Может, соответствуют, а может не соответствуют. Особенно, если ваша "кириллица" пришла из какого-то другого места. Кириллица разная бывает

Comment: CrazyElf, не подскажите, как скачать страницу в правильной кодировке? Спасибо

Comment: insolor, скачивание страницы сайта, ее html-структуру.

Comment: @Эникейщик, вполне возможно, ведь разные сайты могут использовать разную кириллицу. Не знаете ли вы, что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо за помощь, но решение находилось на поверхности. Достаточно лишь было указать кодировку вручную при определении контекстного менеджера:

```python
with open('index.html', 'w', encoding='UTF-8') as file:
```

Comment: Код нужно добавлять текстом, а не скриншотами. То же самое по коду в вопросе.

Comment: Да, по умолчанию файл записывается питоном в винде в кодировке `cp1251`. Это её родная кодировка.